# What does it mean for an operator to be diagonal with respect to an orthonormal basis?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

Suppose that you have a seperable Hilbert space, $H$, an orthonormal basis of $H$, $(e_n)$, and the set $D=\{T\in B(H):T\,\text{is diagonal with respect to the basis}\,(e_n)\}$.

**Problem:** What, exactly,  does it mean to say that an operator is *diagonal with respect to an orthonormal basis*?

As a particular example, if you were to take two operators in this space, say, $S,T\in D$, how would you verify that the composition $S\circ T$ was also in $D$? Which properties of an operator being in $D$ would you be checking this product against?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means that the set of vectors $e_i$ are eigenvectors of the operator, i.e. there exists a set of values $\lambda_i$ such that 
$$Te_i = \lambda_i e_i.$$
In your example, suppose that both $S$ and $T$ verify the above, with possibly different eigenvalues $\sigma_i$ and $\tau_i$, then for every vector in your basis you have
$$S(T e_i) = S(\tau_i e_i) = \tau_i Se_i = \tau_i\sigma_i e_i$$
Therefore the composition $ST$ also belongs to your set $D$, with the product of eigenvalues of $S$ and $T$.

Note that I used the word vector but I suppose you understand how to treat general vector spaces. Also, orthonormality is not needed.

Comment: In the first line you should really have $\lambda_i$, it's not the same $\lambda$ for each vector (in general).

Comment: Sure, corrected the typo, thx

Answer (score 3):

It means that $Te_n=\lambda_n e_n$ for some values $\lambda_n$. If you write down the operator as a matrix w.r.t. that basis, it would be a diagonal matrix.

Stated differently, all $e_n$ are eigenvectors of $T$. The $\{e_n\}$ are an eigenbasis of $H$ w.r.t. $T$.

---

If $S,T\in D$, then $STe_n=\lambda^T_n Se_n=\lambda^S_n\lambda^T_n e_n$. So yes, $ST\in D$ again.

Comment: Then we can say for any operator with matrix representation of diagonal form is a diagonal operator with respect to the standard basis, yes?

Comment: @Amin What do you mean by standard basis? The operator is diagonal w.r.t. the basis to which he gives a diagonal matrix. An operator can be *diagonalizable*, while not being diagonal w.r.t. your chosen "standard basis".

Comment: I meant that a diagonal matrix is actually is a representation of a diagonal operator? (standard basis is the simplest basis: $e_i$ has entry $i$ equal to $1$ and $0$ otherwise).

Comment: @Amin I suspect some misunderstanding, but I am not sure. A general Hilbert space may not have a "standard basis" as described by you (you probably think of $\Bbb R^n$, including $n$ infinite). With your statement "a diagonal matrix is a representation of a diagonal operator", I agree, almost. But note that an operator is not just "diagonal", but "diagonal w.r.t. some basis"! Without stating a basis, it is called *diagonalizable*. In the same way, an operator has many matrix representations, some of which might be diagonal matrices, and there might be several distinct diagonal matrices for it.

Answer (score 2):

It means: $T \in D \iff $ each $e_n$ is an eigen vector of $T$.

Comment: Why the downvote ?????